# Can we call class Library from a wcf service

Tags: wcf, class-library

Can we call class Library from a wcf service...sorry if the question is wrong..
the method in the class

```
public class DocItem       
public DataSet GetRecord(int ID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string Type, string pocType)
```

Comment: could you show the code that you are currently using to try and call the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Simply `Add a Reference` to the `Library` in your `Project`.  Then add in the `using` namespace and you'll be able to instantiate the objects from the DLL.

Comment: I did Add the reference and created an object to access the methods in the calls but i am unable to see any methods

Comment: @Gani - maybe the access modifiers on the method are private

Comment: when i tried to access a method in class it says "a field intializer cannot reference the non static field,method or property" the method is public and it returns a dataset

Comment: i created a object for the class and when i type the object dot,i cannot see the intellisense at all

Comment: Have you built the project since adding the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

If the class library supports running in an unattended manner, then yes. If the functionality you require from it would cause UI to pop up, then you may have to try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

A class library is going to be nothing more than a DLL in your service... why wouldn't you be able to?